# Tell eclipse to use Source and not Jar

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have a maven project that depends on a jar (say A). When running the project, it uses the jar under Maven dependencies.

I have the source of A with me and its opened as a project in Eclipse. When I run the project I need to use the source and not the jar. How do I tell Eclipse to use the source and not the jar?

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse does this by default, if that is a full Maven project. See the context menu in the screen shot of http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/eclipse.html#eclipse-sect-resolving-dependencies, where it says "Disable workspace resolution".

If you don't find that context menu entry for your project, then you probably have a Java project with a POM file, which is not marked as Maven project type in Eclipse. Use the context menu *Configure->Convert to Maven project* in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the workspace resolution of [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse) as well. It would recognize the dependency (A) and show a different icon in the dependency view (which indicates that the dependency is resolved from the workspace) but the classes were not found.

Only when I ran a `mvn install` on project A all artifacts were generated and the resolution started to work. Maybe that helps.

Also I found a couple of hints (related to not working workspace resulotion) that suggested to `(re-)import` the project again using "Existing Maven Projects" wizard.